# Spring Cloud Data Flow propagating arguments to tasks

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Can someone please explain how to pass arguments from a composed task to an independent task within the composed task. By default the arguments passed to composed tasks are not propagated to the task.

Answer (score 0):

We have documented the support for ["app properties"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks) in the recent 1.5 M1 release. There are also a few samples.

There's a PR to add support to "deployer properties", too [[spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2156](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/2156)]. Let us know if you have any feedback.

Comment: I checked your suggestion, but it looks like this is about passing properties to child task. I am looking for propagating arguments (not properties) from composed task to individual tasks. For example if I've composed task to which I am passing a load-date as argument, I need to access that in the child tasks.

Comment: Ah! You can pass args to child-tasks via CTR property. See [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-task-composedtaskrunner/README.adoc#options) for more details. In your case, you'd pass it via `composed-task-arguments` property.

Comment: Currently, all the composed task arguments that are passed as `--arguments` when launching are passed to the child tasks. But, there isn't a way to pass the arguments for a specific child task similar to how we pass `properties`.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of SCDF this is working?